# Build filter for post-type + multi taxonomies + multi terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, terms, sql

I Need to build an interface with a filter set (a list of checkboxes) that the user can check and click 'filter' to search with in 1 custom post-type for posts with matching terms (there are 3 custom taxonomies with each an unlimited amount of terms).

*How to go about this? I am thinking to code the following:*

I displayed the GUI filterlist like this (x3 because there are 3 taxonomies):

```
<form action="/filter-result" method="get">
    <?php $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    foreach($terms as $term) {
         echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="taxonomy-name" value="' . $term->name .'">' . $term->name . '</label>';
    } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

I end up on the `/filter-result` page with an URL with more than one parameter that all have the same name:
`filter-result/?taxonomya=term1&taxonomya=term2&taxonomyb=term9`

My plan is to GET all the parameters- I don't know how because there are parameters with the same name- and then build an SQL out of the filtered data.

Answer (score 1):

Add brackets to the input names:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="taxonomy-name[]" value="term">term</label>
```

It will be automatically converted to an array:

```
if( isset( $_GET['taxonomy-name'] ) ){
    foreach( $_GET['taxonomy-name'] as $term ){
        echo $term;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Milo's answer for the sake of completeness, this is how I formed the args for the sql using the URL parameters:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'mycustomposttype',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relationship' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomy1',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['mytaxonomy1'],
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomy2',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['mytaxonomy2'],
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomy3',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['mytaxonomy3'],
            'operator' => 'AND',
        ),
    ),
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    }
}
```

See for more elaboration [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54280549/3065848).
I also found this a great resource for making the WP_Query: [WP_Query Arguments: Taxonomies](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp_query-arguments-taxonomies--cms-23090)